# How to place a button over a shape in CSS?

Tags: html, css, shapes

I am creating a website with a login and sign in feature, and want to place the buttons over a solid dark blue background above the gradient but below the buttons. When I try to create a shape, the buttons move down on the website to accommodate room for it, but I want the shape to be on a layer below the buttons but still visible. Is there any way of doing this in CSS? 
If so, how? Thanks :)

Here is my CSS and HTML so far:

HTML:

```css
html {
        height: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        background: #a5fcff;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background: linear-gradient(#00033a, #a5fcff);
    }
    
    .signinbutton {
        background-color: #458af9;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        font-size: 75px;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
     transition-duration: 0.5s;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-top: 225px;
    }
    
    .signinbutton:hover {
     background-color: #a7acb7;
    }
    
    .createaccbutton {
        background-color: #458af9;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        font-size: 75px;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
     transition-duration: 0.5s;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-top: 100px;
    }
    
    .createaccbutton:hover {
     background-color: #a7acb7;
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Debate Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class = "square"></div>
    <button class = "signinbutton">SIGN IN</button>
    <button class = "createaccbutton">SIGN UP</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:
Sorry, I want the website screen to look like this:
[Login Screen mock-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guE0k.jpg)
But it currently looks like this:
[Actual login screen so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xBOf.jpg)

Comment: For this question it's probably worth adding a picture of what you want to end up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `position: absolute;` as mentioned above. If you end up with something on top of another (covering up the thing underneath) then you can use `z-index: [number];` to specify what is on top of what.

Answer (score 0):

You can position the element **absolute** relative to the html or another container.

example style:

```
.square {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #f00;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

[Working example](https://codepen.io/sygn/pen/LXaMqW)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

**1)** First, edit your *html, body* style.

```
html {
  height:100%
}
body {
  background: #a5fcff;
  background: linear-gradient(#00033a, #a5fcff); /* background first, followed by the other options */
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed /* for repeating gradient */
}
```

**2)** Customize `.square` element if you want.

```
.square {
  position: absolute;
  top:0; /* above the gradient */
  left:0;margin-left:auto;right:0;margin-right:auto; /* center position:absolute element */
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #0000ff
}
```

**4)** Add one `margin` line for buttons and remove others.

```
.signinbutton {
  margin: 225px auto 0 auto; /* 225px for top, auto for right&left, 0px for bottom */
}
.createaccbutton {
  margin: 100px auto 0 auto; /* 100px for top, auto for right&left, 0px for bottom */
}
```